# How to turn reflection light into limited color? (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, color, reflection

heyya, I'm having trouble in making this camera lens:

These glasses are under two same lamps, but turns out different colors

[image]

[image]

I tried a lot to control the color but it always look like a green lens:

[image]
[image]

What can I do?

I'm using cycles renderer and my blender version is 4.0.1

this is the blender file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L90eF6ixLs15Iig2lWmRUol6GO2aONx1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: someone who can help me plz